# How to write subtraction of 2 matrix as multiplication

Tags: inverse, matrix-calculus

In a paper I saw the following equation.
[image]

If I express the equation in a simple way, It comes down to the following equation.
$(I-A)^{-1} - (I-B)^{-1} = (I-B)^{-1} [A-B] (I-A)^{-1} $

How can we prove these are equal to each other?

Thank you

Comment: Hint: $A-B = (I-B)-(I-A)$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hint @JMoravitz

With help of the hint ,the solution is

$$(I-B)^{-1} (I-B) (I-A)^{-1} - (I-B)^{-1} (I-A) (I-A)^{-1}$$
$$(I-B)^{-1} [(I-B)-(I-A)](I-A)^{-1}$$
$$(I-B)^{-1} [A-B] (I-A)^{-1}$$